# Discovering a machines default DNS

Tags: dns, network-programming, network-protocols

I'm writing a small DNS proxy. It listens for incoming UDP messages on a port and resolves them using a specified DNS (e.g. google's DNS 8.8.8.8) and sends the response back to the client.

I would like to be able to detect the default DNS a machines uses. Every OS has an option to obtain the DNS server address automatically. I was wondering how this is done. Is there a protocol on top of UDP or TCP, or something else entirely?

I'm using C#, but the language isn't important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding which DNS the current computer uses as default is highly dependent on both which OS you use and which language you use. If you use Java or .NET, or another platform independent language you might not need to worry about the OS bit though.

Client computers usually "auto-discover" which DNS to use in the DHCP response from the DHCP server. That is when they receive their IP address they also get which DNS server to use. They might also get addresses to WINS servers and a multitude of custom options.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the DNS server by typing ipconfig/all in coand prompt. This will  gove you the address of your DNS server.